# Shared Access moving from windowsazure.storage to Azure.Storage.Files

Tags: c#, azure-storage, c#-3.0, azure-storage-files

For the life of me,  can not get how to set a shared access file policy in the new sdk.
after uploading using the ShareFileClient i need to generate a url for another unauthenticated client to download.
with the old sdk i did something like

```
        var sasConstraints = new SharedAccessFilePolicy() { 
            SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5) , 
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10) , 
            Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read | SharedAccessFilePermissions.List };
        return myCloudFile.Uri + myCloudFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);
```

Any and all pointers to accomplish this in the new sdk is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you want to a sas token for Azure File share with new Azure file sahre sdk. Regarding how to create it, please refer to the following code

1. Install package

```
dotnet add package Azure.Storage.Files.Shares
```

2. Code

```
# create sas token
 string accountname = "<account name>";
 string key = "<storage ket>";
 var creds = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountname, key);
var builder = new ShareSasBuilder
 {
    ShareName = "file share name",
    Protocol = SasProtocol.None,
    StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-1),
    ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(+1)              
};
    builder.SetPermissions(ShareSasPermissions.All);
    var sas = builder.ToSasQueryParameters(creds).ToString();

// test (Upload file)
// Get a reference to a share 
ShareClient share = new ShareClient(connectionString, shareName);

// Get a reference to a directory and create it
ShareDirectoryClient directory = share.GetDirectoryClient(dirName);
directory.Create();

// Get a reference to a file and upload it
ShareFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient(fileName);
using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
{
     await file.CreateAsync(stream.Length);
     var response =await file.UploadRangeAsync(
                    ShareFileRangeWriteType.Update,
                    new HttpRange(0, stream.Length),
                    stream);

     Console.WriteLine(response.GetRawResponse().Status);
}
```

[image]
[image]

For more details, please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/17e4d05b6acb1e375abdc76de3ca02a9e064564b/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Files.Shares/tests/FileTestBase.cs#L122).